# Different animation effects in js

Tags: javascript, animation, version-control

I use this animation effect code with js scroll: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

My js code include a class in the last line:

```
$(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
```

This great, but sometimes i would  like change the fadeInLeft effect (example slideInleft or flipInLeft).
How to add different effect in that line in different div?

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Check if element is scrolled into view
  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }
  // If element is scrolled into view, fade it in
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.scroll-animations .animated').each(function() {
      if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
        $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca specify the animation type in custom attribute in your element.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.scroll-animations .animated').each(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
      $(this).addClass($(this).data("animationType"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="scroll-animations">
  <div class="animated" data-animation-type="fadeInLeft"></div>
  <div class="animated" data-animation-type="flipInLeft"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you so much.